# create a timelog line under line in javascript

Tags: javascript

**simple button** when you click on it it will show the **current date** **but** when you click on it agin it will show the curennt date in another **line** ( date after date) as a **timelog** set in a table. meaning that the time will show inside a box table under box.

the function that gets the date  :

```
Button.addEventListener("click", function Click () {
  document.getElementById("pergraph").innerHTML = Date(); }
```

i cant jest put a **"/n"**...

thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: works great! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append to innerHTML using `+=` rather than assigning with `=`:

```js
Button.addEventListener("click", function Click() {
  document.getElementById("pergraph").innerHTML += Date() + "<br>";
})
```

```html
<button id="Button" type="button">
Add date
</button>

<p id="pergraph">

</p>
```

If you would rather have separate, style-able elements, wrap the date in a span  and style with CSS:

```js
Button.addEventListener("click", function Click() {
  document.getElementById("pergraph").innerHTML += "<span>" + Date() + "</span>";
})
```

```css
#pergraph span {
  display: block;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button id="Button" type="button">
Add date
</button>

<p id="pergraph">

</p>
```